# After Tor project installation, I got error

Tags: proxy, scrapy, tor, privoxy

I am installing tor in my ubuntu 18.04 as per [link](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/04/10/tor-privoxy/).After completing all the steps, i am getting this error

```
$ sudo service tor status
● tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-07-06 11:47:19 IST; 13min ago
 Main PID: 10894 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4554)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tor.service

Jul 06 11:47:19 aks-Vostro-1550 systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Jul 06 11:47:19 aks-Vostro-1550 systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

My /lib/systemd/system/tor.service file is:

```
# This service is actually a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I will be thankful for your help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem in Ubuntu 18.04 using the suggestion given by [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882527/tor-process-will-not-start-automatically-on-ubuntu-16-04/903341)